# dart angular2 - form directive #mymodel="ngForm" not working

Tags: forms, angular, dart

When I put in my template something like

```
 <input id="password" name="password" class="form-control" type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" ngControl="password" #password="ngForm" required minlength="6" maxlength="30">
```

I cannot start my application, I have the following message :

```
 Can't read 'package:website/login_component.template.dart' (Could not find asset website|lib/login_component.template.dart.).
 import 'package:website/login_component.template.dart' as i2;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[Warning from Dart2JS on atthecorner_website|web/main.dart]:
web/main.template.dart:33:1:
'i2' has no member named 'initReflector'.
i2.initReflector();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If I remove the attribute `#password="ngForm"` it works.

My pubspec.yml :

```
name: website
description: website
version: 0.0.1
environment:
  sdk: ">=1.13.0 <2.0.0"
dependencies:
  angular2: 2.0.0-beta.20
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1
transformers:
- angular2:
    platform_directives:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_DIRECTIVES'
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#FORM_DIRECTIVES'
    platform_pipes:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_PIPES'
    entry_points: web/main.dart
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
```

I looked at this repo (https://github.com/angular-examples/forms) which works fine, but I cannot see any differences.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you please try to restart `pub serve` and try again? What IDE are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I already tried but it doesn't work. I use jetbrain's IDE.

Comment: Could be https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6028. The order of transformers matters. Please post the transformers section of your `pubspec.yaml` if your issue is different.

Comment: I added it in my question.

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas.

Comment: Try using `ref-password` instead of `#password`. https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/guide/template-syntax.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

The tag `#property="ngForm"` only works if the `property` is wrapped into a bean acting as the model. If the property is just in the component, it doesn't work.